# Resource Manager - JSON having multiple alerts fails

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-resource-manager

I use below JSON to create AI alert, which works fine. However when I try to add add multiple alerts in this JSON file, it creates few alerts, sometimes one and other times two or three and finally returns provisioning state as **Failed**. It never creates all the alerts in the JSON (six).

```
{
        "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "parameters": {
            "AlertName": {
                    "type": "string"
            },
        "Location": {
                    "type": "string",
             "defaultValue": "East US"
            },
        "ResourceGroup": {
                    "type": "string"
            },
        "ResourceName": {
                    "type": "string"
            }
        },
    "resources": [{
                "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
                "name": "[parameters('AlertName')]",
                "type": "microsoft.insights/alertrules",
        "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
                "tags": {
                    "displayName": "AppInsightsAlert"
                },
                "properties": {
                    "name": "[concat('AppInsightsAlert ', parameters('AlertName'))]",
                    "description": "[concat('App Insights Alert ', parameters('AlertName'))]",
                    "isEnabled": true,
                    "condition": {
                            "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.ThresholdRuleCondition",
                            "dataSource": {
                                "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleMetricDataSource",
                                "resourceUri": "[concat('/subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourcegroups/',  parameters('ResourceGroup'), '/providers/microsoft.insights/components/',  parameters('ResourceName'))]",
                                "metricName": "view.count"
                            },
                            "threshold": 1,
                    "windowSize": "PT5M"
                    },
                    "action": {
                            "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleEmailAction",
                            "sendToServiceOwners": true,
                        "customEmails": []
                    }
                }
        }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PowerShell for deployment - if so, add the -debug switch to the New-AzureResourceGroup* command and sift through the output.  The raw error from the platform is in there and it's usually pretty good.  If that doesn't help, can you post the entire json template for the deployments that are failing?

Comment: I am using Resource Manager API and it doesn't return any detailed error  message. Also, the JSON posted in the question is the one that I use, it works if there is one item (Alert) in the resource array. However, multiple items (Alerts) in the resource group array, makes it fail.

Comment: Ok, the JSON posted above only sets on one alert though... How are you setting up the array?  Are you duplicating the resource or using an array with a copy loop?  Or do you post the same JSON multiple times with different parameter values?

Comment: I am duplicating the resource and then changing name, metricName, etc.